# std::regex_replace only replaces every other match?

Tags: c++, regex

I need to parse json strings (with boost::property_tree::read_json)

Some of the input strings are not valid as they looks like:

```
"[1,2,3,,,,,4]"
```

when they needs to look like:

```
"[1,2,3,null,null,null,null,4]"
```

What is the best way to transform such string?

I have tried

```
//option A:
std::regex rx1(",,");
auto out_str = std::regex_replace(str_in, rx1, std::string(",null,"));
```

and

```
//option B:
auto out_str = boost::algorithm::replace_all_copy(str_in, ",,", ",null,");
```

But both options only replace every other match. As in:

```
"[1,2,3,null,,null,,4]"
```

Fundamentally what I want is not to replace, but to to insert, a substring. Id like to avoid writing back the characters I'm matching for.

Edit:

What I would like is not to consume or insert the commas. Something like

```
//option C 
std::regex rx1(",(),"); 
auto out_str = std::regex_replace(str_in, rx1, std::string("null"));
```

But that doesnt work (possibly because it is the incorrect regex syntax)

Comment: It's not that every other match is being replaced, your replacement string is inserting adjacent commas. Try doing it by hand ... replace the first `,,` with `,null,`, then the next `,,` with `,null,` and see what you end up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex` replaces by searching for a first match, and then replacing it. **Overlapped matches do not take place.** So, if it sees `,,,`, it replaces the first two commas with `,null,`, yielding `,null,,`. But, it doesn't look at what it replaced, just what is ahead of the replacement.
Steps it takes:

1. Finds first match: **,,**,
2. Replaces first match: ***,null,***,
3. Moves on, *and only sees one comma*, since it only looks at the string after the previous search/replace.

So, you're replacing `,,` with `,null,`, but it doesn't look at the comma you used in the replace string `,null,` because it doesn't do overlap matches.

To make sure it *does* do overlap matches, simply run the search and replace on the string twice.

Answer (score 2):

You do not really need a regex to do such a simple task, simple search and insertion would work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string str{ "[1,2,3,,,,,4]" };
    do {
        auto pos = str.find( ",," );
        if( pos == std::string::npos )
            break;
        str.insert( pos + 1, "null" );
    } while( true );
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Run it on [ideone](https://ideone.com/h0NaXt)

Answer (score 1):

Your replacement string is incorrect.  Do it by hand:

```
Start: "[1,2,3,,,,,4]"
Replacement 1: "[1,2,3,null,|,,,4]"
                     ^parsed up to here
Repalcement 2: "[1,2,3,null,,null,|,4]"
                                  ^parsed to here, no more matches
```

You either want to adjust your replacement string, or replace repeatedly until the string doesnt change.

Answer (score 1):

you can call your function twice (although is not an optimal solution)

```
std::string in_str = "[1,2,3,,,,,4]";
std::regex rx1(",,");
auto out_str = std::regex_replace(in_str, rx1, std::string(",null,"));
out_str = std::regex_replace(out_str, rx1, std::string(",null,"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you could go adding a while loop to your option B:

```
auto out_str = str_in;

while (out_str.find(",,") != std::string::npos) {
    out_str =  boost::algorithm::replace_all_copy(out_str, ",,", ",null,");
}
```